# Going from "okay" to "excellent"

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, users

**Final Update:** Now that we've launched, I wanted to update this post with our final numbers:

[image]

Many thanks to everyone who helped make the site a success!

---

**Update 4:** We just crossed over 15 questions per day and are now up to 4 "excellents":

[image]

Also of note is the significant increase in our visits/day from 2,474 to 3,648.

---

**Update 3:** We're back to 3 "excellents" as Studer is now the 5th user to pass 3k rep:

[image]

Also, there was some confusion in the last update about the "questions per day" metric that has since been resolved - it's not over the entire beta of the site but of the [previous two week period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73217/bug-in-area-51s-questions-per-day/73245#73245). This will make it easier to improve - we only need ~35 more questions per week to be over the 15 q/d mark.

Finally, the answer ratio has seen a slight increase. My best guess is that the migration of [this 97-answer question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/terminal-tips-and-tricks-for-mac-os-x) from Super User is what caused it.

---

**Update 2:** The "questions" metric has been changed to "questions per day". As such, we've now dropped from 3 "excellents" back down to 2:

[image]

We are only 1 3k+ rep user away from an "excellent" users rating, so hopefully if we keep voting we'll claw back to 3 "excellents".

Turning back to the questions per day, [the number actually seems flat out wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73217/bug-in-area-51s-questions-per-day). According to Area 51, we've been in beta for 129 days, which would mean that we have ~1303 questions. However, the "Site Stats" box on our site indicates that we have 1648 questions. Either there's a bug, or there has been a change in what questions contribute towards that figure.

Assuming there's a bug, though, we still only have 12.8 questions per day, so we still need to get that ramped up - we're about 300 questions short right now.

---

**Update:** We've passed 1500 questions and are now at 3 "excellents":

[image]

Also of note, we've crossed over 2k visits/day and we have 38 more users with 200+ rep and 2 more users with 2k+ rep. We still need:

- 5 more users with 200+ rep
- 3 more with 2k+ rep
- 4 more with 3k+ rep

as well as increasing our answer ratio to 2.5 answers per question.

---

As many of you probably know, Area 51 has a set of metrics it uses to evaluate the progress of the sites in public beta:

[image]

We've always had an "excellent" percent answered, and as you can see we've recently crossed the 1500 visits/day "excellent" threshold as well. Now I'd like to see what we can do to address the rest of the metrics to bring them up to "excellent":

- **Number of questions** should be pretty easy - at the current rate, we should hit 1500 questions in a little over a week.
- **Number of "avid users"** is going to be harder. In order to get "excellent" in this category, we need to have 42 additional users with 200+ rep, 5 additional with 2,000+ rep, and 4 more with 5,000+ rep. To hit these targets, we'll need to

  - Actively recruit more users to the site. Suggestions about how to do this are welcome.
  - Questions, and especially answers, need to get more votes to increase the rep of the poster. We need to actively promote upvoting good questions and answers.
- **Answer ratio** could also be tricky. In order to bring our existing question base up to a ratio of 2.5 answers per question we'd have to add over 420 answers (give or take, the ratio isn't precise). Of course, getting some answers to the 6% "unanswered" questions should be the top priority, but we should try to encourage users to add alternative solutions to "answered" questions as well.

Thoughts?

Comment: I believe that Jeff & Crew should spawn some love and take us out of beta… we deserve a nice theme :)

Comment: @Martin: create a feature-request :P

Comment: @Martin Me too. I think the current planned launch order is [programmers, money, then RPG](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/180/any-idea-when-this-site-will-come-out-of-beta) (for some reason) but I think we're a good candidate to be the next one after those.

Comment: @Kyle Since SE’s designer is an Apple Boy, at least this will look nice on Safari :)

Comment: @Kyle: i read in one of the chat rooms that they order it goes by is which communities have enough 3k plus users so that the site can be effectively self moderated.  After that it goes by excellent, good, worrying, etc, as far as stats are concerned.  So I think we're pretty good on the stats, but not so good on the community moderation aspect.

Comment: @calavera OK, that makes some sense. It was a bit confusing to me that some sites with less than half our # of questions and visits were scheduled to launch before us.

Comment: @Kyle: strange timing for us to be talking about this... see Jin's new post on meta!

Comment: @calavera w00t!

Comment: @Kyle Link or it didn’t happen! :)

Comment: @Martin I got that info from [here](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/180/any-idea-when-this-site-will-come-out-of-beta), but I suspect that we're actually next in line after RPG as the other sites mentioned don't have any meta posts from Jin

Comment: @Dori OK, I updated to include the new info. I still think it's a good idea to get us in the best shape possible until we actually do launch, as the SE team constantly rechecks the stats and reorders the launch dates of the sites.

Answer (score 5):

Lurking around discussions.apple.com and posting “links” to this site might help. I did that with a couple of questions that had an answer here. :)

Comment: good idea for boosting our user base - any ideas about increasing rep/the q:a ratio?

Comment: @Kyle: yes... have everyone click on my profile, then visit each of my questions/answers and click the little up-arrow.

Comment: i guess that only contributes to the rep situation though :P

Comment: @calavera I've been doing that with users just below the 200 rep threshold. I only had 2 upvotes left today but I gave them to you

Comment: @Kyle not a bad idea, I was doing that with you :) we need you guys to go > 5k!

Comment: @kyle: I was only kidding, but hey, upvotes are all good in my book! :P

Comment: @calavera Well we do need more 3k+ rep users...

Comment: @Kyle I voted many user with rep under 200 to reach the minimum(you can see it easily in my profile :D)

Comment: I've been upvoting a lot more as well, but only when I truly believe the question or answer deserves it... I pushed sentinel up over 2k rep :)

Comment: @Kyle: since we need more 3k users to launch, that's where i've been focusing my voting.  This led me to notice that one of our moderators, hasn't been on the site since Oct 22...

Comment: @calavera I noticed that too, and also that Chealion is no longer a moderator. Effectively, Dori and I are the only active mods on the site.

Comment: Nooooooooo Chealion must come back!